# Targeting previous div in javascript or css

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

HTML code:

```
<div class="content">
   <textarea> hello.png </textarea>
</div>

<div class="content-btn">
   <a href="#" class="button"> Click me </a>
</div>
```

Javascript code:

```
  $(".button").click(function() {
    if ($(this).parent().previousSibling('.content').css('display') == 'none'){
      $('.content').hide();
      $(this).parent().previousSibling('.content').show();
    }else {
      $('.content').hide();
    }
  });
```

How would I go about only showing the textarea when 'Cick me' is clicked or hovered preferably in css but if not javascript. Thanks guys

https://jsfiddle.net/uway5hhg/8/

Comment: `.previousSibling('.content')` will not work, use `.prev('.content')`

Comment: That doesn't seem to work either

Comment: its working bro - https://jsfiddle.net/uway5hhg/10/ you have forgot to choose jquery framework on the left side on jsfiddle.net

Comment: Why don't you just use `.toggle()`? https://jsfiddle.net/uway5hhg/11/

Comment: @ray in your fiddle, you have not included jquery, that's why it's not working. as soon, as you do that, rohits solution will do it.

Comment: cool ill try that @errand

Comment: use @NewToJS fiddle - that's the right one ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As exercise you could do this effect in pure css (using `:target` pseudoclass and a long delay in a simple transition) if you add a *close* button just below the textarea

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JYoMRK

---

```
<div class="content" id="text">
   <textarea> hello.png </textarea><br />
   <a href="#close" class="button">Close</a>
</div>

<div class="content-btn">
   <a href="#text" class="button">Open</a>
</div>
```

---

CSS

```
#text { 
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0s 999999s;
}
#text:target {   
  opacity: 1;
  height: auto;
  transition-delay: 0s;
}

#text:target ~ div a.button { display: none; }
```

---

Anyway if you look for a straight jQuery approach, a simple `toggle()` is enough (you might have to hide the `.content` element via css depending on the initial condition of your textarea)

https://jsfiddle.net/uway5hhg/39/

```
$(".button").click(function() {
    var content = $(this).parent().prev('.content');
    content.toggle();
});
```

Comment: Very nice! I like seeing solutions that match a jQuery outcome. +1 for this!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there is no way to catch previous sibling in CSS.

But it works with jQuery, here is your slightly changed code:

```
  $(".button").on('click', function() {
      var ele = $(this),
          par = ele.parent(),
          sbl = par.prev();
    if (sbl.css('display') == 'none'){
      $('.content').hide();
      sbl.show();
    }else {
      $('.content').hide();
    }
  });
```

Working example is here: https://jsfiddle.net/y0ab3n0L/

Comment: This doesn't work very well for multiple use. https://jsfiddle.net/y0ab3n0L/1/ usually people target a class name to target multiple elements, not just one.

Answer (score 0):

That should do it's job

JS:

```
$(".button").click(function() {
    var contentBtn = $(this).parent(".content-btn");
    var content = $(contentBtn).prev(".content");
    var textarea = $(content).find("textarea");
    $(textarea).toggle();
});
```

or event shorter:

```
$(".button").click(function() {
    $(this).parent(".content-btn").prev(".content").find("textarea").toggle();
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/uway5hhg/21/

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Solution provided by Fabrizio is a good one if you want no javascript. 
However you can also modify the DOM to have a similar effect.

```
<div class="content-wrapper">
    <div class="content" id="text">
        <textarea>hello.png</textarea>
    </div> 

    <a href="#text" class="button">Click me</a>
</div>

CSS
.content {
    display:none;
}
.content-wrapper:hover .content {
    display:block;
}
.content-wrapper:hover .button {
    display:none;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/2Lsszgqz/

Answer (score -2):

There is no such CSS pseudo element - `a.button:click`, so only JS solution will work (***without changing your HTML structure***). You can also get to close of it using `:focus` CSS pseudo class. But you will lack to go up one level in CSS and then show the `textarea`. So, only solution left is using JS.

In your sample JS code you have used `.previousSibling('.content')` which is native JS, which you are calling on jQuery object, that's why it will not work. jQuery equivalent of this function is `.prev('.content')`

**Correct Syntax** would be -

```
$(".button").click(function() {
if ($(this).parent().prev('.content').css('display') == 'none'){
  $('.content').hide();
  $(this).parent().prev('.content').show();
}else {
  $('.content').hide();
}
});
```

[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uway5hhg/10/)